# How to fix 'this.props.router.push' giving 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined' error?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to have my react app go to a new page when a logo is clicked. I have done this in my app on other components but for some reason I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` when I click the logo. This is my component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';


import Logo from './nspstar.png';
import Logo2 from './nspred.png';
import HomeLogo from './HOME.png';
import HomeLogo2 from './HOME2.png';
import MusicLogo from './MUSIC.png';
import AboutLogo from './ABOUT.png';
import AboutLogo2 from './ABOUT2.png';
import ContactLogo from './CONTACT.png';
import ContactLogo2 from './CONTACT2.png';
import ShopLogo from './SHOP.png';
import ShopLogo2 from './SHOP2.png';

export default class Menu extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            imgSrc: Logo,
            homeSrc: HomeLogo,
            aboutSrc: AboutLogo,
            shopSrc: ShopLogo,
            contactSrc: ContactLogo

        }
        ...
        this.goHomePage = this.goHomePage.bind(this);
    }

    goHomePage() {
        this.props.router.push('/');
    }


    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='Menu' id='Menu'>
                <Link to='/'><img onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver2} onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut2} src={this.state.homeSrc}></img></Link> <Link to='/About'><img onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver3} onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut3} src={this.state.aboutSrc}></img></Link> <img src={this.state.imgSrc} onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver} onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut} onClick={this.goHomePage}></img> <Link to='/Shop'><img onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver4} onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut4} src={this.state.shopSrc}></img></Link>  <Link to='/Cart'><img onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver5} onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut5} src={this.state.contactSrc}></img></Link>
                <hr />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm calling `goHomePage() {
        this.props.router.push('/');
    }`

in `<img src={this.state.imgSrc} onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver} onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut} onClick={this.goHomePage}></img>`

What is wrong with my code that is giving me this error?

Comment: What react-router version is this?

Comment: `"react-router": "^3.0.5",` ...I have this working on other components in the app, but in this component it won't work.. @AndrewLi